# ASP.Net MVC Html.Label with Attribute List?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I create an ASP.Net MVC Helper for an Html.Label which takes in attributes?

Currently when I define an Html.TextBox I am able to pass in a list of attributes. Sort of like below:

```
new {disabled="disabled", @class="pcTextBoxWithoutPaddingDisabled"})%>
```

However, it does not look as though the Html.Label has this feature. As a result, I have to define my labels using the label tag.  Sort of like below:

```
<label class="pcLabelBlackWithoutPadding">
```

I would like to be consistent I how my Html element get created.

So, how do I create an Html.Label that will take in a list of attributes?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified Alexandr code a bit with lambda expression, in case anyone needed the lambda expression.

usage:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property , new { @class = "bigFont" })
```

code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, Object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        var innerText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(metadata.PropertyName)));
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(innerText);

        return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

This is updated version for MVC3:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper helper, String htmlFieldName, String labelText, Object htmlAttributes)
{
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(htmlFieldName, helper.ViewData);

    String innerText = labelText ?? (metadata.DisplayName ?? (metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last()));

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText))
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    tagBuilder.SetInnerText(innerText);

    return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest creating your own HtmlHelper extension method and using a TagBuilder to create the label.

```
 public static HtmlHelperExtensions
 {
      public static Label( this HtmlHelper helper, string labelText, object properties )
      {
           var builder = new TagBuilder("label");
           builder.MergeAttributes( new RouteValueDictionary( properties ) );
           builder.SetInnerText( labelText );
           return builder.ToString( TagRenderMode.Normal );
      }
 }
```

See the MVC [source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/22929) for ideas on how to create a strongly-typed label helper.  Note that you'll need to add the namespace containing your extensions either to the page or the web.config to be able to use it.